# In spring batch, what is a scope of an ItemReader without scope="..."?

Tags: spring-batch

If I have a web application, with an application-context that loads everything for my webapp and all my jobs configuration files, and if I have in a job a simple ItemReader without scope="step", the reader is a singleton, right ? So if I launch twice my job from a controller via a SimpleJobLauncher, I will use the same bean, right ? Unless I put scope="step", in order to have one bean per job execution ?

On the other hand, if I launch the job from a CommandLineJobRunner, I will have two distinct application contexts, so two different beans, right ?

Are my assertions valid ?

Thanks

Comment: a caveat here... `step` scope creates an instance per step (so multithreaded partitioned steps will each get their own instance), not just one per job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct. Basically, every Bean-instance in a SpringContext is a singleton.

However, most readers or writers have a state. For instance, FlatFileItemReader can only run once, after that it points to the end of the file and its "close" method had been called. Therefore, if you simply start the job again, it will not work, since the FlatfileItemReader is closed.

For such cases, you will need to define them with sope=step.

Comment: Annotation: @StepScope